# Separating instance creation, attribute update, and instance combination

Tags: python, function, dictionary, parameters, arguments

The Python code I am working on separates instance creation, attribute update, and instance combination (see the simplified example below). Currently, I am relying heavily on dictionaries to manipulate objects, which is a bit clunky? Any idea how I could make my code more pythonic? Thanks!

PS: to be clear, I am not trying to simplify the operations but how the objects are handled in various parts of the code

```
# In practice, there are multiple classes with several variables each
# that do complex operations

class A:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable

class B:
    def __init__(self, variable):
        self.variable = variable


def create_components():
    a = A(variable=1)
    b = B(variable=2)

    return {"a": a, "b": b}

def add_number(components, number):
    a = components["a"]
    b = components["b"]
    
    # The additions below are for illustrative purpose only. 
    # In practice, the code does pretty complex stuff
    a.variable += number
    b.variable += number

    return {"a": a, "b": b}

def operation(components):
    a = components["a"]
    b = components["b"]
    return a.variable + b.variable

def model():
    components = create_components()
    new_components = add_number(components, 1)
    return operation(new_components)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    result = model()
    print(result)
```

Comment: Look into the operator methods, e.g. `__add__`, `__iadd__` etc

Comment: This example is a simplified version of what I am actually working on. In practice, each class is performing different operations that go beyond addition.

Comment: It's good that you simplified your actual code, but it seems in the process of doing that you changed the problem.

Comment: Got it. I edited my question to make it clearer.